# Cant start Node-red

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, node-red

I've tried to install Node-red on Sierra. Used brew to install node and Npm. Then I just followed the instructions on [Node-red](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/installation), but for some reason I can't run Node-red to start it up. I get error message "command not found" ... I've googled like a maniac, without results.

What can I do?

Info:
Osx Sierra 10.13.xx
Node Version 9.11.1
Npm Version 5.6.0

Brew doctor comes out clean.
Brew is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the directory that npm links the executables provided by node modules is not on your path.

Try running `$(npm get prefix)/bin/node-red` in a terminal. If that works, you should add the directory returned by `echo $(npm get prefix)/bin/` to your path.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1081769/after-npm-install-g-command-still-not-found